# Same IF condition isn't working for different Values

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I was solving a real-time problem, like to find common manager for two employees. I was thinking about - Lowest Common Ancestor; anyway, for testing I was creating a demo of LCA problem. My idea was to deep-down in tree and check whether two employee[node] can be reached from the current node, if so - set current node as common and go next level else - return with the last common node found.

But recursion made me wrong!!! And I am stucked here! My codes were :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class LowestCommonAncestor {
 static class BTree{
    int node;
    BTree left, right;

    public BTree(int node) {
        this.node = node;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}

static class Driver{
    BTree addNode(BTree root, int rootNode, char choice, int node) {
        if(root == null) {
            return root;
        }

        if(root.node == rootNode && choice == 'l') {
            root.left = new BTree(node);
        }else if(root.node == rootNode && choice == 'r') {
            root.right = new BTree(node);
        }

        root.left = addNode(root.left, rootNode, choice, node);         
        root.right = addNode(root.right, rootNode, choice, node);

        return root;        
    }

    void display(BTree root) {
        if(root == null) return;

        if(root.left != null)
            System.out.print(root.left.node +" ");

        if(root.right != null)
            System.out.print(root.right.node+" ");

        display(root.left);
        display(root.right);
    }
    boolean isPossible(BTree root, int key) {
        if(root == null) return false;

        if(root.node == key) {              
            return true;
        }

        boolean flag = isPossible(root.left, key);
        flag = isPossible(root.right, key);

        return flag;
    }
    int findLcaDriver(BTree root, int n1, int n2) {
        Queue<LowestCommonAncestor.BTree> queue = new LinkedList<>();           
        queue.add(root);

        int flag = -1;
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {

            LowestCommonAncestor.BTree btree = queue.remove();
            // dive down and checking whether both nodes can be reach from 
            // current node or not
            if(isPossible(root, n2) && isPossible(root, n1)) {
                flag = root.node;
            }
            if(btree.left != null)
                queue.add(btree.left);

            if(btree.right != null)
                queue.add(btree.right);
        }

        return flag;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Driver driver = new Driver();

    BTree root = new BTree(1);

    root = driver.addNode(root, 1, 'l', 2);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 1, 'r', 3);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 2, 'r', 5);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 5, 'l', 12);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 3, 'r', 4);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 3, 'l', 17);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 4, 'r', 11);
    root = driver.addNode(root, 4, 'l', 10);

    System.out.println("Lowest Common Ancestor of these two Nodes is: "+driver.findLcaDriver(root, 2, 0));
  }
 }
```

Comment: ok, so which is the conditional statement that has a problem and for which values?

Comment: there i was sending two node's value such as 2 and 0, but it was failed in function 'findLcaDriver()'

Comment: I hope you understand this does not clarify anything

Comment: @Stultuske  to checking two employee's [i.e, node here] last/lowest common ancestor, i was calling function named findLcaDriver(node1, node2) and i was checking what is the last common employee found, which can be reach from both of them.

Comment: again, you still haven't said which conditional statement doesn't work, and which values (and datatypes) it's comparing. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Stultuske how many if-condition are written in findLcaDriver function? if you not interested, please avoid .. and yes i checked and debugged my code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197323/discussion-between-returnzero-and-stultuske).

Comment: hii sir, if you construct a BT from the input i am given, you'll able to see 2 and 0 are fallen left and right side of the root. since i was trying to reach from the root to both 2 and 0, since both are possible(though it was my assumption), and i was going down.. until i a node from where i can't reach both 2 and 0. if it was given two nodes which comes in the same side of root, then it's working.. but if it is not in same side, problems arise .. i hope i'm cleared to you!

Comment: You added 32 as subnode of 0 before adding 0 as subnode of 3. Can you tell how your program will behave in that case?

Comment: Currently, `isPossible` only return true when subnode is on the right. The result `flag` from left recursion is ignored.

Comment: @aka.nice yes, i did this wrongly! but even if i correct this, still not getting desired output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete working one.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class LowestCommonAncestor {
    static class BTree {
        int node;
        BTree left, right;

        public BTree(int node) {
            this.node = node;
            this.left = this.right = null;
        }
    }

    static class Driver {
        BTree addNode(BTree root, int rootNode, char choice, int node) {
            if (root == null) {
                return root;
            }

            if (root.node == rootNode && choice == 'l') {
                root.left = new BTree(node);
            } else if (root.node == rootNode && choice == 'r') {
                root.right = new BTree(node);
            }

            root.left = addNode(root.left, rootNode, choice, node);
            root.right = addNode(root.right, rootNode, choice, node);

            return root;
        }

        void display(BTree root) {
            if (root == null)
                return;

            if (root.left != null)
                System.out.print(root.node + " ");

            if (root.right != null)
                System.out.print(root.right.node + " ");

            display(root.left);
            display(root.right);
        }

        boolean isPossible(BTree root, int key) {
            if (root == null)
                return false;

            if (root.node == key) {
                return true;
            }

            boolean flag = isPossible(root.left, key);
            if (!flag)
                flag = isPossible(root.right, key);

            return flag;
        }

        int findLcaDriver(BTree root, int n1, int n2) {
            Queue<LowestCommonAncestor.BTree> queue = new LinkedList<>();
            queue.add(root);

            int flag = -1;
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

                LowestCommonAncestor.BTree btree = queue.remove();
                // dive down and checking whether both nodes can be reach from
                // current node or not
                if (isPossible(btree, n2) && isPossible(btree, n1)) {
                    flag = btree.node;
                }
                if (btree.left != null)
                    queue.add(btree.left);

                if (btree.right != null)
                    queue.add(btree.right);
            }

            return flag;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver driver = new Driver();

        BTree root = new BTree(1);

        root = driver.addNode(root, 1, 'l', 2);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 1, 'r', 3);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 2, 'r', 5);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 5, 'l', 12);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 3, 'r', 4);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 3, 'l', 17);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 4, 'r', 11);
        root = driver.addNode(root, 4, 'l', 10);

        System.out.println("Lowest Common Ancestor of these two Nodes is: " + driver.findLcaDriver(root, 17, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for time and reply; but not get any changes in findLcaDriver() method .. and frankly i was not getting that line -- isPossible() has to be checked on the node you remove from queue and not on the root.. will you explain please .. :)

Comment: Have pasted the complete solution. Answer to  driver.findLcaDriver(root, 17, 4) should be 3 right ?

Comment: hey, thanks a lot mate!! cheers! but still i think, i was right on the 'deep-dive-down' concept in 'findLcaDriver()' method [but sorry me, i put root everytime to check.. how could I !!! :( :( ], but the thought was excellent and accurate that -- ' we have to check the right node only if the left node is 'false'!! anyway, happy for you!